# Correct method to initialize a database table with web2py DAL.define_table()

Tags: python, database, web2py

I am trying to dynamically build tables called `db.blog` and `db.code` with exactly the same SQL definitions.  After I define them, I want to populate them with 10 rows of random data, and never execute that initialization code again.

My problem is that the initialization code executes every time I hit refresh on the browser while I view the newblog appadmin interface for `db.code` or `db.blog`: https://172.25.1.1/newblog/appadmin/select/db?query=db.code.id>0

I initialize `db.blog` and `db.code` in `newblog/models/newblog.py`:

```
from gluon import *
from gluon.contrib.populate import populate

## initialize db.blog and db.code: 
##     At runtime, build TAGGED_TABLES (once)
TAGGED_TABLES = set(['blog', 'code'])
for tt in TAGGED_TABLES:
    if not db.get(tt, False):
        db.define_table(tt,
            Field('name', length=32, notnull=True),
            Field('value', length=65535, notnull=True),
            Field('tags', type='list:reference tag', unique=False, notnull=False),
            )

        populate(db.get(tt), 10)

        ## cross-reference db.tagged_tables to this one
        db.tagged_tables.insert(name=tt,
            database_pointer='reference %s' % tt)
        db.commit()
```

Somehow `if not db.get(tt, False):` allows multiple executions of the routine below it.  I don't understand why... if the table has already been created, then `not db.get(tt, False)` should be `False`.  However, web2py never skips the initialization code, which means `db.blog` and `db.code` grow by 10 entries on each reload.

**Question:** Why isn't `if not db.get(tt, False):` preventing multiple executions?

I am running web2py 1.99.4 on Debian 6.0 / sqlite 3.7.3 / Cherokee 1.2.101 / uWSGI 0.9.9.3

### Solution

Based on Interrobang's answer the correct way to write this is:

```
from gluon import *
from gluon.contrib.populate import populate


TAGGED_TABLES = set(['blog', 'code'])
for tt in TAGGED_TABLES:
    # db.define_table() must be called on **every page**
    #    this sets things up in memory...
    db.define_table(tt,
        Field('name', length=32, notnull=True),
        Field('value', length=65535, notnull=True),
        Field('tags', type='list:reference tag', unique=False, notnull=False),
        )

    ## initialize db.blog and db.code: 
    ##     At runtime, populate tables named in TAGGED_TABLES (once)
    if not (db(db.get(tt).id>0).select()):
        populate(db.get(tt), 10)
        ## cross-reference db.tagged_tables to this table (named in var tt)
        db.tagged_tables.insert(name=tt,
            database_pointer='reference %s' % tt)
        db.commit()
```

Now `db.blog` and `db.code` stay a constant size.

### Summary

`db.define_tables()` must be called for every page rendering; my understanding (that it only needed to run once to write the table definition to disk) was incorrect.

Comment: +1 for nice summary of solution.

Comment: @Interrobang, thank you.  I upvoted as well.  Your understanding was key to making this work right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a fixtures file, which basically contains default data to be inserted once, when the table is created.

An example is given here: http://thadeusb.com/weblog/2010/4/21/using_fixtures_in_web2py

Comment: that is good information, and I likely will go this route in the future; however, I'm still wondering why my code is broken.

Comment: While I'm not sure on the `db.get()` syntax, `db.define_table` isn't something you run just once to create the table. It also defines your model and should run on every page load (though web2py is smart enough to not recreate your table if it exists, it will attempt to update the table if the model changes). So db.get() has nothing to get, since you haven't defined the model yet.

Comment: `db.get(<tablename>, False)` was my attempt at checking to see whether the table had been initialized in the database.  Since `db` behaves like a python dictionary, that looked like the right incantation; however, based on your input, I need to do something else.